# java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@38699c6: Unmarshalling unknown type code 1279544898 at offset 12472

Tags: android, kotlin

I am getting this crash, not in every device but I can see those crash in crashlytics.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
```

Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sankhep.news/com.sample.news.view.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@38699c6: Unmarshalling unknown type code 1279544898 at offset 12472

Here is my onCreate Method of Main Activity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    //window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
    category=intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.EXTRA_CATEGORY)
    postId=intent.getIntExtra(Constants.EXTRA_FEED_ID,-1)
}
```

I m using kotlin and Parcelize for parcelable implementation

here is my Parcelable class

```
@Parcelize
class Category(val name:String,
               val categoryid:Int,
               val image: Image
               ):Parcelable {
}
```

Comment: Please check `val image : Image` Image class is Parcelable or not. If not, then make it Parcelable

Comment: Yes it is parcelable.



@Parcelize
data class Image(val path:String,val new_name:String):Parcelable{
    fun getImageUrl():String{
        //http://sankhep.com/beta/admin/uploads/posts/post_1222811848.png
      return Constants.BASE_URL+Constants.STAGE+"admin/"+path+new_name
    }
}